# SQL Server: How to Get Large amount of JSON from Store Procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I've created one store procedure that returns the JSON. But it not return complete  JSON only limited JSON returned. I used "For JSON auto" after Select statement. Have any Solution to get all JSON?

Comment: Do you mean the Json text is getting truncated?

Comment: @JayasuryaSatheesh, Yes

Comment: Post your query here than only we can identify why your json result is getting truncated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are using any Cast or covert operations. Use VARCHAR(MAX) instead of VARCHAR().

I have seen this issue in such cases.

Also if you are using the print output, then it is possible that the text might get truncated, but you can use the Select or Output parameter instead.

make the output parameter of type nvarchar(max)

or check this link :

[Format Query Results as JSON with FOR JSON (SQL Server)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/format-query-results-as-json-with-for-json-sql-server)

This might help

Answer (score 0):

I found my solution here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/format-query-results-as-json-with-for-json-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15#output-of-the-for-json-clause (same as above, but a specific section)

The issue was that I thought SQL Server was returning a single row/cell of JSON data because that is how SSMS displayed it. The truth is that it chops it into multiple rows.

I was retrieving the data in .NET using `ExecuteScalar()`, but I needed to use `ExecuteReader()`, and concatenate all rows together. Once I did that, I could deserialize the JSON without issue.